# How to change sub-template in template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I try to make a template that include template in it. Is it possible to pass html file name to include?

Now I use this code.

```
{% include "edit_course.html" %}
```

but I want to replace "edit_course.html" with value from context instead.

```
{% include {{name}} %}
```

How can I do this?

Edit: This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST")
        return render(request, 'main.html')
    else:
        print(request.GET.get('opt', ''))
        if request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'new_student':
            return render(request, 'main.html', {'url': 'new_profile.html',})
        elif request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'new_crew':
            pass
        elif request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'new_course':
            pass
        elif request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'edit_student':
            pass
        elif request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'edit_course':
            pass
        elif request.GET.get('opt', '') == 'report':
            pass
        else:
            pass

        return render(request, 'main.html')
```

Comment: Did you try just `{% include name %}`?

Comment: I already try that but I got "ID or literal expected".

Comment: @HelloWorld can you show your vews,py?

Comment: @Johny Beebop I already add my views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your template:

`{% include url %}`

But it is better to rename 'url' to 'template_name' or something in this string `return render(request, 'main.html', {'url': 'new_profile.html',})`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by **passing** the **name** of **sub_template** to the **main template** in the **view** that **loads** the **main template** like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
render(request, "mainTemplate.html", context={"name":"edit_course.html"})
```

in your `mainTemplate.html`:

```
{% with name as sub_template %}
    {% include sub_template %}
{% endwith %}
```